# Не работает пагинация в Wordpress WP Page Navi

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Вот код.

```
 <?php
    global $post;
    $args = [
     'post_type'      => 'flats_moscow',
     'posts_per_page' => 2
                    ];
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    query_posts($args);
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        if( have_rows('flat_thumb') ):
            while( have_rows('flat_thumb') ) : the_row();
                $flatThumbTitle = get_sub_field('flat_thumb_title');
                ?>
                <p><? echo $flatThumbTitle; ?></p>
                <?
            endwhile;
        endif;
    }
        if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

На странице выводятся две записи. Всего их три. Но пагинация все равно не работает. Как решить этот вопрос?

Comment: https://0-wp--punk-com-0.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/wp-punk.com/ne-zabujte-s-vashej-paginatsiej/amp/?amp_js_v=a3&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQFKAGwASA%3D#aoh=15989850864075&amp_ct=1598985091873&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=%D0%A1%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwp-punk.com%2Fne-zabujte-s-vashej-paginatsiej%2F

Comment: Все равно не сработало. По ссылке выше получается бесконечный цыкл вывода тайтла последней записи.

Comment: Добавьте внутри цикла $query->the_post();

Comment: Добавил в цикл foreach И выдает ошибку   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function the_post() on nul . В цикл while тоже добавлял